# Lucene: query date range, including empty values?

Tags: date, lucene, range

I'm querying lucene for values over a date range, like so:

```
field:[YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00 TO YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00]
```

This returns hits for anything in that date range that has actual results. However, it doesn't return the *entire* range, which would be ideal.

Here's an example of what is *currently* returned for a search of `field:[2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 TO 2000-12-31T23:59:59+00:00]`, if there are only values for July (pseudocode):

```
[{date: 2000-07-01, value: 12345}]
```

But I'm wondering if I can get a return that looks like this:

```
[
  {date: 2000-01-01, value: 0},
  {date:2000-02-01, value: 0},
  ...
  {date:2000-07-01, value: 12345},
  ...
]
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of the required output? If you want any date then you can use field:[* TO *]

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what the internals look like; we reach out via API to retrieve our data, so all I know is what comes out after it's been massaged.

Comment: Reading the question I am not clear what you're trying to achieve. If the document doesn't have a value in the relevant field then we don't have a way to understand if it's in the range or not. Are you asking how to return all the docs in that range AND all the documents that have field empty? Please edit your question with a clear example of what you need. It doesn't need to be coded, it's just to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Done! Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: There is still something missing. You might want to post the query that you're using cause date:[2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 TO 2000-12-31T23:59:59+00:00] will return exactly what you're looking for as you don't have constraints on the field named 'value'.